# You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server LAMP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost

i have the following problem in accessing to my /localhost/phpmyadmin

I hope you can help me

> ```
> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request
> ```

.

Comment: Check folder permissions if you're running Unix/Linux. Also, have a look to your webserver log to have more information on the error.

Answer (score 0):

The folder do not have the required permissions to access it. Please go to the folder where your server is pointing to and give it Read and execute access.

chmod -R 755 /path/to/folder

and you can make the folder accessible through web .

Answer (score 0):

Here you have two errors:

1. You need to check the permission of folder ../phpmyadmin
2. The 403 error is an Apache one, have a look here to fix it:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-403-forbidden-error-and-solution/